# Ajax file upload in Wordpress - can't pass FormData

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, file-upload

I've made a script which uses $.ajax and FormData to pass two form objects to PHP. One form object is a text and the other is a file.
It worked well as a stand-alone script. However, after I added it to Wordpress, as a plugin, it keeps giving me `"Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"`.

I can't afford to serialize the formdata, simply because then I won't be able to pass the file to the callback function in PHP.

JS involving FormData before ajax call:

```
var fd = new FormData();
var file = jQuery(this).find('input[type="file"]');
var caption = jQuery(this).find('input[name=img_caption]');
var individual_file = file[0].files[0];
fd.append("file", individual_file);
var individual_capt = caption.val();
fd.append("caption", individual_capt);
```

This part above is 100% correct.

Ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: fiuajax.ajaxurl,
    data: {
        action: 'fiu_upload_file',
        security: fiuajax.security,
        data: fd,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    },
    success: function(response){
        var dataObj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        if(dataObj.message == 'error') {
            jQuery('.fiu_validation').html('The following error occured: '+dataObj.desc);
        }
        else if(dataObj.message == 'success') {
            jQuery('.fiu_file').val('');
        }
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

This is incredibly frustrating since it worked perfectly fine outside of Wordpress. I've tried de-registering Wordpress' jQuery and enqueueing the latest jQuery version, but it made no difference.

To recap:
1) Ajax/jQuery is refusing to pass a form object to PHP
2) Can't serialize the object because I need to preserve the file object
3) Script works outside of Wordpress
4) Tried updating to the newest jQuery version, no change

Comment: fiuajax.ajaxurl = correct url for wp ajax?

Comment: Yep, I double-checked both ajaxurl and security nonce. I tried doing the call through $.post, but no luck either.

Comment: ok show your php so.....basically if you put `echo "hello"; ` in your code and in your success function console.log(response). The jQuery looks correct so once the ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>' if its not firing its your add_action hook has a mistake

Comment: When I comment out data: fd from ajax call, everything is working well. But  when I add data:fd, it gives me a Javascript error. So PHP is definitely correct.

Comment: What is the error? you prob should show your html output as well..

Comment: I mentioned the error in the question. I get this "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation". I'm getting it because I'm trying to pass an object. I can't serialize it, because the form object contains a file object and I'd lose the file if I were to serialize the entire formdata object.

Comment: you need to go back over your previous q's and accept answers as well (tick mark beside the answer!)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

try this :

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var fd = new FormData();
    var file = jQuery(document).find('input[type="file"]');
    var caption = jQuery(this).find('input[name=img_caption]');
    var individual_file = file[0].files[0];
    fd.append("file", individual_file);
    var individual_capt = caption.val();
    fd.append("caption", individual_capt);  
    fd.append('action', 'fiu_upload_file');  

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: fiuajax.ajaxurl,
        data: fd,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response){

            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

php

```
function fiu_upload_file(){

    var_dump($_FILES);
    exit();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_fiu_upload_file', 'fiu_upload_file');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_fiu_upload_file', 'fiu_upload_file');
```

Comment: It doesn't work :/ processData and contentType are the reasons why the 0 is being returned. Also, contentType is not sending multipart/form-data at all. Instead it's sending plain text. I checked the formdata and it seems okay, so it's not that. It's so weird. It must something with Wordpress.

Comment: well the 0 means you havent put exit(); in your php function....ill test the above code on a wp installation now and see whats up.

Comment: I tried both exit() and die(), but no luck. Thanks for your help though, I appreciate it. I decided to take a non ajax-based approach.

Comment: ok you might accept this as the correct answer anyway, it helps other people who come across this!

Comment: It was a good effort, but doesn't work for me using the latest wordpress

Comment: @gray its tested and confirmed to be working using the latest wp. Check over the code again!

Comment: I've tried it again, but still get 0 response - tried exit() and die() too

Comment: Hi @David, you're right it does actually work - the problem was that my ajax url (fiuajax.ajaxurl above) didn't include a nonce.. I added this to my php :--  'upload_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '?action=upload_image&nonce=' . wp_create_nonce('image_upload_nonce') -- and it worked

Comment: glad to hear that. Btw remove fiaajax from the url and the security field for anyone else doing this.

Comment: I get a "Uncaught ReferenceError: fiuajax is not defined". Anyone know why or what it should be?

Comment: Figured it out. Just used url: "admin-ajax.php" and all is well in the world again.

Comment: when .serialize()taken thats time?

Comment: exactly got what i looking for

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do it. The code works on the latest version of Wordpress (4.9.4)

First of all, I'm using XMLHttpRequest to send the data and not the jQuery ajax. This means that you can adapt it to just pure JS.
Notice the `xhttp.setRequestHeader("enctype","multipart/form-data");` which was essential to pass the FormData using this method.

JS:

```js
var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
var picture = $('#userPic')[0].files[0];

console.log(picture);

if( picture && typeof picture !== undefined ) {

  if ( picture['size'] > 1000000 ) {
    alert('The Profile Pic can\'t be larger than 1Mb.');
    return;
  }

  if ( picture['type'].indexOf('image') == -1 ) {
    alert('The uploaded file needs to be an image.');
    return;
  }

  var data = new FormData();
  data.append('user_id', user_id);
  data.append('userPic', picture);

  // console.log(data);

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log('Receive:' + this.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", location.origin + "/wp-content/themes/search-and-go-child/ajax/upload_user_profile_pic_ajax.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("enctype","multipart/form-data");
  xhttp.send(data);

}
```

The PHP part is also extremely useful since it requires the files needed to manipulate the received data with the WP core functions.
Here you will also find the code to upload an attachment using the WP core functions.

PHP:

```
    // error_reporting(-1);
    // ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    require_once($path.'/wp-load.php');
    require_once( '/home/s24t06b21lk5/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php' );
    // require_once("/home/s24t06b21lk5/public_html/wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once("/home/s24t06b21lk5/public_html/wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    // require_once("/home/s24t06b21lk5/public_html/wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');


    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $picture = $_FILES['userPic'];


    var_dump($user_id);
    var_dump($picture);

    $response = array();

    if( isset($picture['name']) && $picture['name'] ) {

        // Get the path to the upload directory.
        $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();           

        $picture['name'] = preg_replace( '/[^0-9a-zA-Z.]/', '', basename( $picture['name'] ) );

        // Upload the file
        $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
        $upload_result = wp_handle_upload($picture, $upload_overrides);
        // echo '<pre>'; print_r($upload_result); echo '</pre>' ;

        if( $upload_result['url'] ) {

            // Prepare an array of post data for the attachment.
            $attachment = array(
                'guid'           => $upload_result['url'], 
                'post_mime_type' => $picture['type'],
                'post_title'     => $picture['name'],
                'post_content'   => '',
                'post_status'    => 'inherit'
            );


            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $upload_result['file'] );

            if( $attach_id ) {

                // Make sure that this file is included, as wp_generate_attachment_metadata() depends on it.
                require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

                // Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
                $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $upload_result['file'] );
                wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

                // Update the usermeta table with the uploaded avatar
                if( !update_user_meta($user_id, 'wp_user_avatar', $attach_id ) || !update_user_meta($user_id, 'wp_zfgrf5v7rw_user_avatar', $attach_id) ) {
                    $response['result'] = FALSE;
                    $response['message'] = "The uploaded image could not be associated with the User ID in the database.";              
                }
                else {
                    $response['result'] = TRUE;             
                }


            }
            else {
                $response['result'] = FALSE;
                $response['message'] = "Wordpress attachment post for the user's image could not created.";
            }

        }
        else {
            $response['result'] = FALSE;
            $response['message'] = "The file couldn't be uploaded. Check the permissions.";
        }

    }

    die( json_encode($response) );
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you describe what you are doing here that is different and important? The important bits should be readily viewable in your answer.

Comment: Of course:

First of all, I'm using XMLHttpRequest to send the data and not the jQuery ajax. This means that you can adapt it to just pure JS.
Notice the .setRequestHeader("enctype","multipart/form-data") which was essential to this method.

The PHP part is also extremely useful since it requires the files needed to manipulate the received data with the WP core functions.
Thank you.

Comment: The details should be added to your answer. Click 'edit'

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2):

Works whith any input(one or many simple or multiple), textarea, select in your form (WP 5.0.3)

```
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this);
        var formdata = (window.FormData) ? new FormData(form[0]) : null;
        var data = (formdata !== null) ? formdata : form.serialize();

        formdata.append("action", "fiu_upload_file");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: fiuajax.ajaxurl,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            status: 200,
            data: formdata,
            success: function(data){                    
                if(data.error == 'true') {
                    $('.msg').html(data.true);                          
                }
                else {
                    $('.msg').html(data.false); 
                    // your code if you want an action ...                                                                          
                };
            }
        });
    });
```

and php for only the files

```
    foreach ($_FILES as $file) :
        if($file['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) :
            continue;
        endif;

        $valid_ext = array( 'jpg' , 'jpeg' , 'png' , 'doc' , 'docx' , 'pdf' , 'xls' , 'xlsx');
        $extension_upload = strtolower(pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if ( in_array($extension_upload,$valid_ext) ) :
            $name_upload = uniqid() . $file['name'];
            $url_insert = trailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) ) . 'uploads';
            wp_mkdir_p($url_insert);
            $name_insert = trailingslashit($url_insert) . $name_upload;
            $action = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],$name_insert);
            $msg_true = 'Upload ok ';
        else :
            $msg_error = 'Upload error';
        endif;
    endforeach;

    $result = !isset($msg_error);
    $msg = array();

    if($result) :
        $msg['error'] = 'true';
        $msg['true'] = $msg_true;
    else :
        $msg['error'] = 'false';
        $msg['false'] = $msg_error;
    endif;



    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

I added

```
 dataType: 'json'
```

and it helps.
Full listing of your code of Ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: fiuajax.ajaxurl,
    data: {
        action: 'fiu_upload_file',
        security: fiuajax.security,
        data: fd,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    },
    success: function(response){
        var dataObj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        if(dataObj.message == 'error') {
            jQuery('.fiu_validation').html('The following error occured: '+dataObj.desc);
        }
        else if(dataObj.message == 'success') {
            jQuery('.fiu_file').val('');
        }
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here some modified code in case you have multiple data and multiple files

```
var fd = new FormData();
var data = jQuery('#yourformID').serializeArray();
jQuery.each(data,function(key,input){
    fd.append(input.name,input.value);
});
var file = jQuery(document).find('input[type="file"]');
jQuery.each(jQuery(file), function(i, obj) {
    jQuery.each(obj.files,function(j,file){
        fd.append('files[' + j + ']', file);
    })
});
fd.append('action', 'fiu_upload_file');
```