# How to insert image with text field into custom table in database?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

How to insert image with text field custom table in database?

```
<form method = "post" action = "#">
     <label for="name">Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="name"/><br>
     <label for="description">Description</label>
     <input type="text" name="description"/><br>
     <label for="phone">phone</label><br>
     <input type="text" name="phone"/><br>
     <label for="name">Image</label>
     <input type="file" name="image"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sub_submit"/>
</form>
```

---

```
<?php

function insert_query() {

  $name         = $_POST['name'];
  $description  = $_POST['description'];
  $phone  = $_POST['phone'];

  $img = $_FILE['image']['name'];
  $img2 =time().$img;
  $folder = "echo bloginfo('template_url')/pic/".$img2;
  $tmp = $_FILE['image']['tmp_name'];
  move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder);

  global $wpdb;
  $table_name = "wp_insert";
  $sss = $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('name' => $name, 'description' => $description, 'phone' => $phone, 'image' => $img2 ),array( '%s', '%s', '%d', '%s'));

    if($sss)
    {
        echo "Done";
    }
    else 
    { 
    echo " Not Done";
    }
  }

if( isset($_POST['sub_submit']) ) insert_query();
```

========OutPut===========
[image]

Comment: where is your php file located( or which theme/plugin file you used )?

Comment: file location theme,custom template used, HTML code form.php in theme folder and php code in functions.php

Comment: your superglobal name is wrong: not `$_FILE`, but `$_FILES`

Comment: Thank you for reply.I have used $_FILES but not work,same result  showing

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in your code, which not allow your image to be uploaded into theme folder.

> Form processing and file upload provided below is not suggested to use for WordPress.

You can use some tips from WordPress Codex, such as [`wp_handle_upload()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_handle_upload/) and etc. Also, can take look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763501/wordpress-form-with-file-upload-submit-with-ajax/49847877#49847877).

1. HTML part of your code should be:

   ```
   <form method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <label for="name">Name</label>
       <input type="text" name="name"/><br>
       <label for="description">Description</label>
       <input type="text" name="description"/><br>
       <label for="phone">phone</label><br>
       <input type="text" name="phone"/><br>
       <label for="name">Image</label>
       <input type="file" name="image"><br>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sub_submit"/>
   </form>
   ```

   We removed `action` attribute, because don't know, which file should process it. Also, added [`enctype="multipart/form-data"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype) attribute => value for handling file upload.
2. PHP part should be something like:

   ```
   function insert_query() {
       $name         = $_POST['name'];
       $description  = $_POST['description'];
       $phone  = $_POST['phone'];
       $img = $_FILES['image']['name'];
       $img2 =time().$img;
       $folder = get_template_directory()."/pic/".$img2;
       $tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
       move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder);
       global $wpdb;
       $table_name = "wp_insert";
       $sss = $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('name' => $name, 'description' => $description, 'phone' => $phone, 'image' => $img2 ),array( '%s', '%s', '%d', '%s'));

       if($sss)
       {
           echo "Done";
       }
       else
       {
           echo " Not Done";
       }
   }

   if( isset($_POST['sub_submit']) ) insert_query();
   ```

   - PHP superglobal is [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)
   - [`bloginfo()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/) printes values, but we need to get it ( not print ). So, we can use [`get_bloginfo()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/) instead, or other related function. I used [`get_template_directory()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory/) function.
   - the folder named 'pic' should be created, because [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) will not create folder, if it not exists
   - `$img2 =time().$img;` side note for this part: it will be more nice to have image name as `1545769627_name.jpg`. Your code will create image name like `1545769627name.jpg`.

Also, as another note. There are a lot of security holes in your code. I don't suggest you to use it into any other projects besides localhost.

Other parts should work as expected.