# admin-ajax return status 400 when I try to Ajax file upload in WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm kind of new in the WP world. After reading tons of posts I still can't get the simple Ajax file upload working on WordPress.

What I'm trying is to store in database - name, email, and resume. If I remove the input file field the name and email are stored correctly to the database.

Currently, my form looks like this

```
<form method="post" id="applicantform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
     <?php wp_nonce_field( 'my_nonce' ); ?>
     <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
     <div class="upload">
         <input type="file" id="upload-resume" name="upload-resume" />
     </div>
     <input type="submit" name="submit_form" id="submit_form" value="Send" />
</form>
```

The js part is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 

    $('#submit_form').click(function(e){ 

        var applyformData = document.getElementById("applicantform");
        e.preventDefault(); 

        //ajax call 
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST', 
            url: myajax.ajaxurl, // ajax url you assigned! 
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,   
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 
                action: 'applyform',
                formdata: applyformData, 
            }, 

            // Displaying succes message 
            success: function( data ){ 

            }, 

            // Displaying error message 
            error: function( request ){ 
                console.log(request); 
            } 
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

And this is the function in my `function.php`

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_ajax_scripts'); 
function my_ajax_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/formSubmit.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'myscript', 'myajax', array( 'ajaxurl' =>   admin_url( '/admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

function applyform(){
    $valid_extensions = array('pdf' , 'doc' , 'ppt'); // valid extensions
    $path = wp_basename( $uploads['baseurl'] ); // upload directory

    if(!empty($_POST['name']) || !empty($_POST['email']) || $_FILES['upload-resume'])
    {
        $resume = $_FILES['upload-resume']['name'];
        $tmp = $_FILES['upload-resume']['tmp_name'];

        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($resume, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        $final_resume = rand(1000,1000000).$resume;

        if(in_array($ext, $valid_extensions)) 
        { 
            $path = $path.strtolower($final_resume); 
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path)) 
            {
                $table = 'UPC_jobs'; 

                $data = array( 
                    'customer_name' => $formdata_array['name'], 
                    'customer_email' => $formdata_array['email'], 
                    'customer_resume' => $path 
                ); 

                $format = array( 
                    '%s', 
                    '%s', 
                    '%s'
                ); 
                $success=$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format ); 
            }
        } 
        else {
            echo 'invalid';
        }
    }    
}
```

Current error is `Status Code: 400` for admin-ajax.php.

Can anyone help a bit

Comment: (HTTP) 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing). Do you get any error in console? if so what is the error? also try to check if your form submit is working

Comment: Yes, I read that too. That's why I posted the question since I can't see what is wrong. No errors in console. Also, as I wrote if I remove the file input from form and from php part data is saved in the DB. So, it must be something file field.

Comment: try **$('#submit_form').on("click", function(){** and try to use simpler function first to check if your form submit works. also make sure you've using jQuery. also try using && here *if(!empty($_POST['name']) || !empty($_POST['email']) || $_FILES['upload-resume'])*

Comment: When I add `$('#submit_form').on("click", function(){`, I've got `Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined`. jQuery is working fine, after all I'm able to store name and email in database when I remove the field for file.

Comment: use *$('#submit_form').on("click", function(e){*

Comment: Yes, tried it. Still error 400. In the network tab when I click on `admin-ajax.php` I see request payload - [object Object]

Comment: What does the error log show (if anything)?

Comment: Sorry, no error. Just on Network tab I see admin-ajax.php in red and when I click on it I see 400 status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below things in your code

1. You need to add two hooks in your function.php file in order to process form data for both logged in user and non logged in user.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_applyform', 'applyform');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_applyform', 'applyform');
```

2. For ajax file upload check link
   [WP admin ajax file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125376/ajax-file-upload-in-wordpress-cant-pass-formdata)
3. Add Nonce

In your js part

```
data: { 
    action: 'applyform',
    formdata: applyformData, 
    ajax_nonce : myajax.ajax_nonce 
},
```

In your function.php file

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_ajax_scripts'); 

function my_ajax_scripts(){
......
wp_localize_script( 'myscript', 'myajax', array( 'ajaxurl' =>   admin_url( '/admin-ajax.php' ), 'ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('security') );
}

function applyform(){
check_ajax_referer( 'security', 'ajax_nonce' );
.......
}
```

Further check wordpress documentation : [WP admin ajax](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. about the 1) I have them, for 3 what to write in the function.php?

Comment: @Ivanov 
In your my_ajax_scripts() function , replace function wp_localize_script() with below line of code
`wp_localize_script( 'myscript', 'myajax', array( 'ajaxurl' =>   admin_url( '/admin-ajax.php' ), 'ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('security') );`

In applyform() function add below line of code at the starting of function
`check_ajax_referer( 'security' );`

Let me know if this is helpful or not:)

Comment: No, when I add nonce I've got `403 error` which is `403 Forbidden`

Comment: Sorry. can you change code to this `check_ajax_referer( 'security', 'ajax_nonce' ); `under applyform() function and try again?

Comment: Sorry but still same `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()` for admin-ajax

Comment: I'm accepting you answer because the linked thread helped me and the issue is resolved now. The file is successfully uploaded and the path is stored in the database. Thank you!